# Installing Anaconda3 without hardcoded paths

Tags: installation, anaconda, miniconda

I would like to eventually have an Anaconda3 installation in a location that I do not have write access to. I am able to install it in one directory and then request that it be copied to the final location. During the installation, the package asks for an installation location:

```
Anaconda3 will now be installed into this location:
/<path>/<username>/anaconda3

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below
```

The path that I put can eventually be found in the header files and binary files in the final, installed package. This is a problem because the directory will be copied to the destination location. How can I make the package location independent or have the headers, etc. point to the final path?